# Install Ubuntu on empty SSD *while* booted in Windows 10?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am running Windows 10 and want to install Ubuntu 16.04 onto an empty SSD in my box.

I downloaded an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop ISO but when I mount it, there is no autoplay or install.exe that allows me to select a disk. I didn't really expect one but not sure the easiest way to get it on the ssd.

Can I install it it WHILE BOOTED in Windows 10 or do I have to save the ISO to a thumb drive, boot to that and install it on the SSD?

Comment: Change your BIOS option to boot from the cd drive

Comment: Use the ISO to create a bootable pendrive and in your lappy's/pc's bios select boot from usb. Restart your pc, after that the ubuntu installation screen will guide you further.

Comment: Cool... I used Rufus and created a bootable USB... but... when I get into my BIOS and choose that as boot option 1, or even just boot overide and choose the Ubuntu USB, it still boots into Windows 10. Do I need to do anything special to the USB stick with Ubuntu?

Comment: @KirkRoss try this.. http://packard-bell-scandic.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6814/~/enabling-the-boot-device-menu

Comment: @DarshanMiskin I can access the boot menu, no problem, but when I choose the Ubuntu Thumb drive (which appears as a bootable device in BIOS) it *still* boots to Windows 10. My guess is something is corrupt on the thumb and it's falling back to the next bootable device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You *must* create a bootable volume (USB stick, DVD), i.e., you cannot boot into Windows, install Ubuntu on empty drive, then boot into that new installation.

My problem in the comments above was an anomaly... I had my USB stick in a USB port on the top of my case, as opposed to one of the main ports on the back, directly connected to the motherboard. Not sure why that would make a difference, but it did.

I also re-created the boot USB (again using Rufus) but this time checked the box for "Check for bad blocks" as a precaution. It took longer, and I'm not sure if it found any, but after creating the new Ubuntu boot stick and putting in a main USB port, it showed up in my BIOS as a UEFI USB whereas before it was just a USB volume.

Now... I just have to figure out how to pick the friggin install location because I got fairly far into the installation steps and it looked as if I was going to overwrite my Windows installation so I have to do some more snooping.